# Calculate Days Between Dates excluding Sundays

Tags: cognos

Would anyone be able to help me calculate the number of days between two dates excluding Sundays in Cognos? I would also like to count the next day as the first counted day. For example, if something was picked up on a Monday, the first counted day would be Tuesday.

I was using this logic however it is not what I need

1 + 5 * (_days_between (cast([Finish] as date);cast([Start] as date))
-_day_of_week (cast([Finish] as date);1)+_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date);1))/7

- if (_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date);1) > 5) then (6) else  (_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date);1))

- if (_day_of_week (cast([Finish] as date);1) > 5) then (5) else (_day_of_week (cast([Finish] as date);1))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked.

Comment: sample input and expected output data please

Answer (score 0):

If the database column with the dates is continuous, meaning it is not missing any date records you could try:

```
total(if ((_day_of_week ([Introduction date],1<>7 ) and( [Introduction date] between _add_days(?startDate?,1) and ?EndDate?))
```

then
(1)
else
(0))